# How to move a file with Box API-V2 from one folder to another

Tags: box-api

Can someone give the correct format for nesting the field name in a PUT to change the parent folder ID for a given file

tried

'parent.id'
'parent:id'

Answer (score 0):

The `parent` is a class with an `id` property.  As such:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
-d '{"parent": {"id" : "NEW_PARENT_ID"}, "name" : "NEW NAME"}'
-X PUT
```

**EDIT**: Added `name` to example at asker's request.

Comment: Thanks that worked, one more question, how would it look if I did a file rename and a file move in the same command

Comment: I added the `name` to the data field in the example.  The field is formatted in [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/), if that wasn't clear.